# how do you share data between viewmodels in Flutter Provider state management?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I am new to flutter Provider state management. If each view has its own viewmodel, how do you share data between viewmodels?
Lets say you have a viewmodel with a list in it, in one screen you want to show the list, and in another screen you want to show the list count?

Comment: Do you have any code?

Answer (score 0):

You can place `ViewModel`s on the top of widget tree, before `MaterialApp`

```dart
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: <SingleChildWidget>[
        ChangeNotifierProvider<ViewModel1>(create: (_) => ViewModel1()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<ViewModel2>(create: (_) => ViewModel2()),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp( ... );
    );
  }
}
```

so you can access both viewmodels everywhere